# Finding nearest distance between point and polygon layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, distance, distance-matrix, spatial-analysis

I am using QGIS to undertake an analysis for a project.

This involves a polygon shapefile, which represents a boundary of a site, and a series of points which represents the location of parks.

I am able to create labels and numbering of the points quite easily through the custom labeling tool and related queries.

Is there a way to calculate/show the points which are closest to the site boundary (shape polygon) rather than having a random numbering approach?

Which means the closest to the site would say be number 1 and the furthest away would say 12.

Comment: What kind of distance do you mean `"Euclidean distance"` or `"Manhattan distance"`?

Comment: Check the nnjoin plugin. Read carefully the description, at first sight is what you are looking for : "The NNPlugin joins two vector layers (the input and the join layer) based on nearest neighbour relationships. All geometry type combinations are supported. A feature from the input layer is joined to the nearest feature in the join layer. The result of the join is a new vector layer with the same geometry type and coordinate reference system as the input layer."